# how to set accessKeyID for an Amazon S3 client in C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have the following code an it is not working correctly.
I suspect my issue is one of security. Therefore I want to make sure I can set the security settings correctly.
Anyone knows how to set accessKeyID in an AmazonS3Config object?

```
    public static AmazonS3Client InitS3Client()
    {
        string accessKeyID = "jfjfjfj"; 
        string secretAccessKeyID = "jfjfjf";
        AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config
        {
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast2
        };

        return new AmazonS3Client(config);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static AmazonS3Client InitS3Client()
{
    string accessKeyID = "jfjfjfj";
    string secretAccessKeyID = "jfjfjf";
    BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID);
    AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config
    {
        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast2
    };

    return new AmazonS3Client(creds, config);
}
```

Try creating a `BasicAWSCredentials` object first and passing that into your `AmazonS3Client`.